# Nexus Jenkins Plugin: how to inject Server URL dynamically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, nexus, sonatype

I'm using the Nexus Jenkins Plugin for the uploading artifacts to the Nexus IQ server.
It looks like this inside the pipeline code:

```
sh "curl http://nexus-artifact-server/***/artifact.war --output artifact.war"
nexusPolicyEvaluation failBuildOnNetworkError: false, iqApplication: 'artifact.war', iqScanPatterns:  [[scanPattern: '**/*.war']], iqStage: 'build', jobCredentialsId: ''
```

nexusPolicyEvaluation is a built-in function of the Nexus Jenkins Plugin which is doing some POST-requests to the IQ Server I think. The actual Server URL is configured inside Jenkins's system configuration i.e. it is hardcoded.

[image]

Is there any way to resolve and inject the URL dynamically? In some cases I may need a two different Nexus IQ servers but the Plugin constraints me with the single one.

Unfortunately can't find any related info at the [official page](https://books.sonatype.com/sonatype-clm-book/1.34/html/book/integrating-jenkins-2.x.html)

Comment: If you're using IQ, you should be entitled to support help from Sonatype (if not you, then your company), FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to configure a several Nexus IQ instances via the Jenkins Nexus Plugin. Which is a little bit strange because some teams may decide to use one IQ instance for dev, one for testing etc.

The soultion is the official [Nexus IQ CLI](https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-iq-cli). Works and configures perfectly.